# PGRouting analyzegraph

Tags: pgrouting

I got an error message when I try to execute the command

```
SELECT  pgr_analyzeGraph('Highway','the_geom',0.0001);
```

Error message:

```
function pgr_analyzegraph(unknown, unknown, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pgr_analyzeGraph('Highway','the_geom',0.0001);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I confirmed that the pgrouting, postgis, postgis_topology is included in the database.

What is the possible cause of this message?

Answer (score 2):

It's the ordering of arguments.

In your initial query, `pgr_analyzeGraph('Highway','the_geom',0.0001)`, you should swap the 2nd and the 3rd argument.

Since `'id'` is the default value of id field, there is no need to explicitly pass it in. You may try `SELECT pgr_analyzeGraph('Highway_empty', 0.00001, 'the_geom')` and it should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `SELECT pgr_version();` to see which version you have installed?

If it doesn't find the function, this could be caused by

- you installed an old version of pgRouting
- the function arguments are different (but they look OK in your case)
- the functions are installed into a different schema, or your `public` schema is not in the search path

Comment: The version is 2.0.0,pgrouting-2.0.0,0,f26831f,master,1.41.0).

Comment: I added the field 'id', it works now!                                 SELECT pgr_analyzeGraph('Highway_empty', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'id')                                                               Anyone can tell me why? I just follow the official material.